# Doctrine 2 - how to join column from another entity without create real column in table?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have Entities 
Language , Route, Page. Language is related to Route and Route is related to Page. I need automatic language entity when I get page. 
Is possible join language entity to page entity without create column in page table?

```
class Language {

......
}

class Route {

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="languages_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @var Language
 */
protected $language;
}

class Page {

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Route")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="routes_id")
 * @var Route
 */
protected $route;

/**
 * Is possible join language Entity without create column in page table?
 */
protected $language;

}
```

Comment: Another possibility other than a join column would be creating join table between `language` and `page`. http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to get the language on the page entity by using the *@JoinTable* annotation. The [Doctrine manual](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table) has a section on how to do this.